# LinearLayout ignored height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a `DrawerLayout (main_activity_drawer)`, `LinearLayout (main_activity_drawer_container)` (used as menu) and one `LinearLayout (show info)`.

The problem is this third LinearLayout have **height** ignored by Android. I set a #CDCDCD background for tests. How I can set height for this LinearLayout and why android ignore the height ?

**What I have (Picture Link)**

> [image]

**Activity Layout (XML)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/gmap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_activity_details_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:background="#CDCDCD">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="What's Up!"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_activity_drawer_container"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_background_bitmap">

        <include layout="@layout/main_activity_menu"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: In my opinion, there is nothing wrong. The color and height are correct. It is just not visually prominent as background color is also  #CDCDCD. Please change this to #FF0000 and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: I set DrawerLayout background to #FF0000 (red) and third LinearLayout background to #0000FF (blue). [RESULT](http://i.imgur.com/QTwgSqC.png). I don't know why but android is ignoring the height.

Comment: Which is the "third" linear layout? Can you tell the `id`?

Comment: main_activity_details_container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem might be with fragment you have used it's having

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

this might be taking up more space that is why height gets ignored
try to use weight concept.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the linearlayout above the fragment. This will definitely give some space to the linear layout.

Are you testing the code on emulator? If yes, then try to run the code on device the UI can be quite different than on emulator(sometimes).

Otherwise using weights is your best option.